# Change name in universal package of sbt-native-packager

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I want to attach sbt-native-packager to a root-aggregate of a project, but that root project has published name for Maven of `"foobar"`. I want the artifact generated through `universal:packageBin` to consistently use `"foo"` instead.

How do I accomplish this?

I tried

```
name in Universal := "foo"
executableScriptName in Universal := "foo"
```

etc. None has an effect. I end up having `bin/foobar` and `bin/foobar.bat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`executableScriptName` is not properly scoped, so you have to do the following"

```
executableScriptName := "foo"
```

Comment: Which version of sbt-native-packager are you using? https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/universal/UniversalPlugin.scala#L69 looks correctly scoped

Comment: Sorry. This peace of code is responsible https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/archetypes/JavaApp.scala#L107